# js update array in function

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a text-based javascript and html game where you have to collect items. There is a html page for each location in the game the user can go to, and they can move freely between locations.

I have made an empty array for the inventory and a function that determines whether the user has already picked up the item(s) in that location.

```
function fieldItems () {
if (inventory.indexOf("paper") === -1 && inventory.indexOf("string") === -1) {
    var fieldItems= prompt("There is string and paper \n Do you: \n A -pick up the paper \n B -take the string \n C -take both \n D -leave both").toUpperCase();
} else if (inventory.indexOf("string") === -1){
    var fieldItems= prompt("There is string. \n Do you: \n B -take the string \n D -leave it").toUpperCase(); 
} else if (inventory.indexOf("paper") === -1) {
    var fieldItems= prompt("There is paper\n Do you: \n A -pick up the paper \n D -leave it").toUpperCase();
} else {
    confirm("The field is empty.");
}; 
if (fieldItems === "A") {
    inventory.push("paper");
    confirm("You pick up the piece of paper.");
} else if (fieldItems === "B") {
    inventory.push("string");
    confirm("You take the string.");
} else if (fieldItems === "C") {
    inventory.push("paper");
    confirm("You pick up the piece of paper.");
    inventory.push("string");
    confirm("You take the string.");
} else {
    confirm("You do not pick anything up.")
};
```

However, when I leave the page and go back to the location, it does not remember the the items pushed to the inventory.

Is there a simple way that I can have the program remember the updated inventory between pages and when I return to the location?

Thank you.

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Variable values in javascript work for the page where they are defined. Cross page values passing is not possible with this way

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you leave a html page, all javascript vars are deleted, a great way to bypass this is to use AJAX (with jQuery).

You have your page, and on each link, instead of

```
<a href="mypage.html"> Link </a>
```

use

```
<a onclick="$('#main').load('mypage.html');" href="#"> Link </a>
```

Then, all your javascript vars (including arrays) will be conserved.

(Obviously, you need to put all your code between `<div id="main"></div>` , if not, It will not work ! :p